# Custom product type can not be deleted from cart: "Cannot remove the item."

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-product-type

I've created a custom product type and use it to create products programmatically via SOAP. The strange thing is if I add the product to the cart I can not remove it via the delete link, it alerts me that it "Cannot remove the item.". Manually creating a product of that type gives the same error.

If I create my product via SOAP using the `simple` product type however it works. I've not come across this issue before. Any ideas?

The delete URL differs:

custom product type: `/checkout/cart/delete/id/27994/uenc/aHR0cDovL2Rldi5jb25maXNlcmllLmRvY2tlci9jaGVja291dC9jYXJ0Lw,,/`

simple product type: `/checkout/cart/delete/id/27995/uenc/aHR0cDovL2Rldi5jb25maXNlcmllLmRvY2tlci9jaGVja291dC9jYXJ0Lw,,/form_key/u8AsmNXOi8nzJ8d0`

`Company/ConfiguratorProduct/etc/config.xml`

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <type>
            <configurator translate="label" module="configuratorproduct">
                <label>Configurator Product</label>
                <model>configuratorproduct/product_type</model>
                <is_qty>0</is_qty>
                <price_model>configuratorproduct/product_price</price_model>
                <index_data_retreiver>configuratorproduct/catalogIndex_data_configuratorproduct</index_data_retreiver>
                <composite>0</composite>
                <price_indexer>downloadable/indexer_price</price_indexer>
                <can_use_qty_decimals>0</can_use_qty_decimals>
            </configurator>
        </type>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

`Company/ConfiguratorProduct/Model/Product/Price.php`

```
class Company_ConfiguratorProduct_Model_Product_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
{

}
```

`Company/ConfiguratorProduct/Model/Product/Type.php`

```
class Company_ConfiguratorProduct_Model_Product_Type extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract
{
    const TYPE_CONFIGURATOR = 'configurator';
}
```

`Company/ConfiguratorProduct/Model/CatalogIndex/Data/ConfiguratorProduct.php`

```
class Company_ConfiguratorProduct_Model_CatalogIndex_Data_ConfiguratorProduct extends Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Data_Abstract
{
    public function getTypeCode()
    {
        return Company_ConfiguratorProduct_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURATOR;
    }
}
```

[image]

Magento 1.9.x